# Ambiguous column reference "ctid" in SELECT with more than one table

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++, mfc, odbc

I'm using `CRecordset` to query one table, but I use a second table to filter data. If in my `GetDefaultSQL` override method I return a table list with more than one table then I get this ERROR: column reference "ctid" is ambiguous. I know what a "ctid" column is, but I don't use it in my code. It's inserted into the original SQL statement by ODBC driver. How to fix this? How to tell the ODBC driver not to insert the "ctid" column?

I tried to call `CRecordset::Open` with `readOnly` parameter, as I assume that ODBC needs `ctid` to update the row, and I don't need to update them. But the error remains.

Also tried to add a primary key to the second table that was missing it, thinking if a table has a primary key then ODBC can use that instead of 'ctid', but again no luck. Makes sense though, because I don't fetch any column of that second table, and the second table is used just for filtering.

If I make a DB view to work around the issue, I get ERROR: column "ctid" does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `CRecordset::Open` with two parameters changed:

```
m_pSet->Open(CRecordset::snapshot, NULL, CRecordset::readOnly);
```

Then you can fetch both the joined tables and the view without errors. No "ctid" then.